# How to get the euid of a process?

Tags: command-line, process

Is there a way to get the `euid` (effective user ID) of a process in Ubuntu without installing any software?

Answer (score 3):

The user returned by `ps` (eg in `ps aux` or `ps -ef`) is the effective user by default.  If you want the effective user id as well you need to add `uid` to the format line, for example:

```
ps -eo pid,user,uid,args
```

The above will show the effective user ID after the effective user name.  Note that `euser` and `euid` are just aliases of `user` and `uid` respectively.

These are distinct to the real user and real user id which would require adding `ruser` and `ruid` in the ps format line.  Typically, effective user (the default) is what you want.  Real user is mainly just a mechanism to remember the original uid before changing uid using setuid (the mechanism used by sudo and su).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and when I type your command, it gives me this error: "error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)"?

Comment: `ps aux` is the BSD syntax, try the `ps -ef` or the longer syntax I had below on its own line.